# [jBPM][Workbench]>Where is the log file?

Tags: jbpm

When a user is logging out the KIE Workbench a message is furtively shown less  and disappear..where can I find out this error message ? in which file or part of the workbench ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All logs are here:

/standalone/log/server.log

Comment: thanks but these logs are the one of the Jboss server not the workbench application log...

Answer (score 0):

**for windows it is here :**

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\log
```